# Google Map API seems to not load

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with a google map on my website not loading but there is still something in the container except a white background, indeed I can see the terms at the bottom right and the satellite button at the top right.

There is the code, I hope you will be able to spot what is wrong :

```
function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.724305, 4.716567);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatLng,
          zoom: 17,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

        var image = {
            url: '/media/A.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(56, 67),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 67),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(56, 67)
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

Comment: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` (remove the parentheses  after initialize) . When it doesn't fix the issue we need to see more code.

Comment: [Your code as posted works for me when I assign a value to `mapcanvas`.](http://jsfiddle.net/47h3mguz/)  How do you define that? What does your HTML/CSS look like (just what is relevant to the map).

Answer (score 0):

In you code `mapCanvas` seems to be unassigned. After adding something like `var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');` the map loads as intended.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DainZX/aeyv4rje/)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

I've added googleapis link "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">.

And I've changed `var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);` to `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);`

And i have removed empty parentheses in the maps event listener.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
       #map-canvas {
           width: 600px;
           height: 600px;
       }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.724305, 4.716567);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); 
    var image = {
        url: '/media/A.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(56, 67),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 67),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(56, 67)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```